# MySQL Search Query

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design

I am creating a system to store user stat data as follows:

```
Table Stats
===========
id    name
-----------
1     height
2     weight
3     eye_colour
4     etc...
```

```
Table Stat_Options
==================
id    stat_id    name
1     1          170cm
2     1          172cm
3     1          174cm
4     2          60kg
5     2          65kg
```

And I store the Ids of the stat_options in the user table as follows:

```
Table User_Stats
================
id    user_id    height    weight    eye_colour    etc...
---------------------------------------------------------
1     10         3         5         7
```

The reasoning behind storing the Ids was that the 'name' of the stat_option can always be changed and the user record would not need to be changed.

But looking at this I think it may present a problem, especially when searching. For example if I want to search for all users between two specific heights? One solution that comes to mind is to insert a 'value' field in to the Stat_Options table, but I'm still unsure if that would work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM STAT_OPTIONS WHERE stat_id = 1 AND name BETWEEN x AND y` - what's hard about that?  Join to the STATS table if you need to get the stat_id based on the name value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this type of design is that you are mixing quantitative values (height, weight) with qualitative values (eye_colour) in your `Stat_Options` table. If you absolutely want this, break down quantitative and qualitative values into 2 columns.

```
Table Stat_Options
==================================
id   stat_id   name   value  unit
===  =======   =====  =====  =====
  1        1   170cm    170     cm
  2        1   172cm    172     cm
  3        1   174cm    174     cm
  4        2    60kg     60     kg
  5        2    65kg     65     kg
  6        3   black   NULL  black
```

Then as other suggested, `JOIN` tables to get values `BETWEEN x AND y`.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to store the qualitative values as integers (in the value column)? For example black=1, brown=2, and so on...?

Comment: @GSTAR: You could do so... Or you can even leave `value` and `unit` to `NULL`, as you won't really use them anyways.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you should use a lookup table like your `Stat_Options` only for cases where the attribute has a finite number of values, like eye color. Trying to use a table like this for attributes that (theoretically) have an infinite number of values, like height and weight, will, as you've already guessed, cause major headaches. I'd store those values directly in your `User_Stats` table instead.

Comment: Ideally I want to avoid storing values directly in my user table, I would rather just reference an ID and retreive the name of that selection from the linked table. This way I can always update the name of the selection without having to update all user records with the new name.

Comment: OK, but in your example of height, would you ever want to modify the name in `Stat_Options` from 170cm to 190cm. You'd suddenly change the height of every user who was assigned that ID, which you'd clearly not want.

Comment: That's true but what I was more concerned about is if I decide to swap between units.. depending on site feedback I may decide to store the height in inches rather than CM. So i wanted to have the flexibilty that i could swap between units without affecting any user data..

Answer (score 0):

From your example, could you get all users with a height between x and y by querying:

```
Select user_id from User_Stats where User_Status.height between x and y
```

Comment: Except that s/he seems to store height with the units included. I do agree, the table needs to be broken out, at the very least, with a value and maybe a units field. From there, a join for the sake of filtering is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id FROM User_Stats WHERE height BETWEEN 170 AND 172;
```

i would guess that one.

But for the structure of your tables i can suggest the following:

1. There is no need for the Stats table since it can be included with no problem inside the User_Stats Table. That way you would normalise better the usage for the tables.
2. IF and only IF the values for height and weight can be more than the 3 you have there (For example 180, 183, 192, 200, 110...) then i suggest the same as point 1. To drop the table and included inside the User_Stats table since this value can change and are not really necessary to make a new table just for that. That way you can do searches faster and easily comparing anything you want in a single table.

Comment: As per my example code, it is not just an integer value (it stores the unit with it).

Comment: I see. So you mean in a hierarchical format. I have heard arguments for and against this format, in the end I decided to stick to keeping everything in separate tables. I don't think putting everything in one table is the solution to this specific problem though.

Comment: You heard against it?. I will point you to a method used for mysql called normalization which, when you read you will see what i was talking about. And remember not to separate too much a database into tables because you will over-normalised 
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Hope that helps to understand the idea of why both tables should be merged.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea to do like this.. Use Stat_option to bind dropdownlist for exemple, in case you have a number never not often changing of values..

why Don't you just add a integer field to the User-stats table with the height?

But if you really want you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_STATS 
INNER JOIN STAT_OPTION 
ON USER_STATS.height in (
 SELECT ID FROM Stat_Options
 WHERE NAME BETWEEN 170 AND 175)
```

Or something like that, i'm not usual with MySql..

Comment: I see. So you mean have a 'value' field alongside name, i.e name="170cm", value="170" ?

Comment: Why don't you put the value 170 in the field 'height' in the datatable 'USER_STATS'? It will be easier.. Not an bond to make tables just for pleasure :-)

Comment: Hmm I suppose that is what I will end up doing!

Comment: Me too because finally you will have a record in the table Stat_option for each user, because as say @Joe Stefanelli you can't change a value for only a user in this configuration..